# how can I convert a string to ip address in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, websocket, tornado

how can i convert a string ip address to a decimal number. e.g I have a data **bytes= b'363,3,1778952384,7076'** , here **1778952384** is my ip address and **7076** is my port. How can I convert my IP address to decimal number. below is my code, please help me to solve these problem

/app.py

```
import socket
from tornado.tcpclient import TCPClient
from tornado import gen

@gen.coroutine
def f(self, message):

    global stream
    client = TCPClient()
    stream = yield client.connect('192.168.8.108', 2620, max_buffer_size=int(1e9))
    msg = '192.168.8.101, 8000'.encode('utf-8')
    yield stream.write(msg)
    data = yield stream.read_bytes(21)
    print("bytes=",data) #bytes= b'363,3,1778952384,7076
```

Comment: why would you do that?

Answer (score 7):

Python has an [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module which can handle this sort of thing. It was added to the standard library in Python 3, but should be installable for earlier versions, too.

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> print(ipaddress.ip_address(1778952384))
IPv4Address('106.8.168.192')
>>> print(str(ipaddress.ip_address(1778952384)))
'106.8.168.192'
```

You may also be asking about splitting the string (on `b','` since it's a bytestring), getting the right field, and converting it to an `int`:

```
data = b'363,3,1778952384,7076'
ipaddress.ip_address(int(data.split(b',')[2]))
```